# Fonts in Windows 7 are different from what they're supposed to be

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I am having an issue with Windows 7 fonts. Someone messed up the default fonts and it is causing an issue with reports and websites where the font is different than what it is supposed to be.

This is causing reports to cut the title off and websites to display links and paragraphs in the wrong areas or being cut off. This issue is only happening on one computer in the entire office. I was wondering if there was any fix or a way to reload the default fonts for Windows 7 even after they have been changed.

I have tried restoring the default fonts through the control panel and that did not fix the problem. I have also ran system file checker to see if there was any issues there that may be causing this to happen.

Comment: What does "messed up the default fonts" mean?  Can you be more specific?  HOW are they messed up?  What's actually wrong here?

Comment: I have edited the question so the issue is described better.

Comment: Brandon, which **web browser(s)** and **application(s)**? Many applications have their own font settings.

Comment: I have found a fix for this issue by running a registry fix from a Deseret Technology Forum post

[here](http://www.deserettechnology.com/journal/windows-7-font-fix)

It resets all the default font registry values and after a reboot everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The fonts used by the system are different from the fonts used by the web browser.  Try changing the web browser's fonts.  I think the default font for IE on our machines is Times Roman 16.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to restore you fonts to default in Windows 7;

1. Open Fonts by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Fonts.
2. In the left pane, click Font settings.
3. Click Restore default font settings.

Comment: he said he already tried the control panel method.

Comment: I have already tried this and it has not fixed the issue.

Comment: @Brandon have you made sure you are logged in as administrator before doing this?  UAC may be holding you up.

Comment: @CharlieRB yes I am signed on as administrator. It does not fix the issue.